# HP Proliant Microserver Gen8 "failed to load module mga" graphics problems

Tags: drivers, gpu-driver, matrox

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my HP Proliant Gen8 but now I can only select 1280x1024 display resolution - but when I used the Live-System I could select more of them.

So I guess there is a problem with the display driver but I could not find the issue.

In Xorg.0.log I found "Failed to load module "mga" (module does not exist, 0)" but I have no idea how to fix this.

**xrandr**

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1280 x 1024, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1024
default connected 1280x1024+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x1024     77.00*
```

**lspci | grep VGA**

```
01:00.1 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200EH
```

**lshw -C video**

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: MGA G200EH
           vendor: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd.
           physical id: 0.1
           bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
           version: 00
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: memory:f9000000-f9ffffff memory:fbee0000-fbee3fff memory:fb000000-fb7fffff
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by manually installing the xserver-xorg-video-mga package.

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-mga
```